# Magento: Decrease stock after a product is added to cart

Tags: magento

I would like to ask for your help to solve a problem. I need to know how to decrease stock not after an order is placed but after the product is added to cart. How can I do this programming? Does anybody have an idea? Yes, I know this is not recommended and it's crazy however I’m working on a development of an online store and the customer (store owner) requested this to my boss and I have to do, simply. Please, anybody could help me with this damn idea?

Thousands of thank you!

Comment: do you know the code of how product is decremented on order? get that code and use it on cart product confirmation page or any other page you want, you will need to alter a bit of code

Answer (score 1):

Even if I strongly not recommend to do so. Here are some advice.

1°) Create your own module, with an event handler on add_to_cart_after.

This event is fired when you successfully add an item to your cart.

2°) Then look at `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` : `subtractQuoteInventory` function to see how to decrease stock.

3°) Now you have to alternate this Observer by rewriting to avoid item removed from stock a second time when order is placed.

Comment: How to create a module? Is there a standard to do that?

Comment: On which page is the event that add a product to cart? Anybody knows?